# How can I fill ggplot area behind geom_pointrange()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Why am I getting the following error when trying to fill area behind other geoms?

```r
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggstance'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     geom_errorbarh, GeomErrorbarh

my_df <- structure(list(group = structure(1:2, .Label = c("group1", "group2"),
                                         class = "factor"), LL = c(-0.0265259354773537, 0.044689036850254),
                       stat = c(0.41037462410532, 0.516457204233787), UL = c(0.847275183687993, 
                                                         0.988225371617319)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .Names = c("group", 
                                                                                                                 "LL", "stat", "UL"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Area to be filled in
rect1 <- data.frame(xmin = -0.2, xmax=0.45, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)
```

The following example works, but I want `rect1` behind `geom_pointrangeh`

```r
my_df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_pointrangeh(aes(y = group, x = stat, xmin = LL, xmax = UL, 
                       color = group)) +
  geom_rect(data=rect1,aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),
            alpha=1,fill="grey70")
```

[image]

This one does not work:

```r
my_df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data=rect1,aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),
            alpha=1,fill="grey70") +
  geom_pointrangeh(aes(y = group, x = stat, xmin = LL, xmax = UL))
#> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

PS: first time using [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/) package to post a question on SO: very nice!

Comment:  on `reprex` use!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pipe into `ggplot2` (ever, really) and "prime" the scales with `geom_blank()`:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_blank(data=data, aes(stat, group)) +
  geom_rect(data=rect1, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax),
            alpha=1, fill="grey70")+
  geom_pointrangeh(data=data, 
                   aes(y = group, x = stat, xmin = LL, xmax = UL, color = group))
```

[image]

Best to avoid using `data` as a variable name, too.

Comment: I'm also curious to know why piping into `ggplot()` should be avoided

Comment: for just this very example. piping populates the main `data` parameter and in more complex plots that can make things very difficult. I also explain more abt my "atomic operations" philosophy of pipes here https://github.com/hrbrmstr/rstudioconf2017

Comment: having said that, for exploratory plots i do pipe, but for "production" workflows (i.e. Rmds I use at work) I never pipe into ggplot2.